# Postrotate "error running shared script"

Tags: mysql, logrotate, ubuntu-14.04

Morning all,

I realise this question has been answered already but the fix does not seem to work in this case so I'm hoping you guys can help. This this is the error I'm getting:

```
error: error running shared postrotate script for '/var/log/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log /var/log/mysql/error.log '
```

This error started occurring after changing my hostname. I am hosting with Digital Ocean so I changed it in their admin area and then went through various programs (like postfix) where it also needed changing. Usually this error is caused by an incorrect password on the 'debian-sys-maint' user, however, I have verified that this password is correct and the user can log into mysql. Just to be on the safe side I went through the steps to fix it but this didn't work. I should also mention that I also changed the hostname on another server hosted with digital ocean and the exact same problem has occured on there so I'm pretty confident the hostname change caused the issue. Both servers are running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

So my question is, does anyone know the reason behind this problem and how to fix it?